# how to get list of users that have posts in django?

Tags: django

I'm trying to get a list of Users that have created at least one Post object. I want to do something like `users = User.objects.filter(posts__not_null)` How can I do this?

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain this with:

```
User.objects.filter(post__isnull=False).distinct()
```

The [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) is useful to prevent returning the same user that much times as there are `Post`s for that user.

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you! Great explanation as well. very helpful